# Expand nested dataframe cell in long format

Tags: r, mongodb, mongolite

Have fetched info from mongo and it looks like this :

[image]

I want to expand part_list in such a way it looks like this :

[image]

Have checked this solution ( [Expand nested dataframe into parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50881925/expand-nested-dataframe-into-parent) ), but it seems to not work in my case.

Also I am unable to create a dataframe like this to post a reproducible code here. How should I expand it ?

Comment: Could you copy/paste the output of `dput(data)` to your post? By that way we can import your data easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unnest()` in `tidyr` to expand a nested column.

```
tidyr::unnest(df, part_list)

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   chapterid part_list
#   <chr>     <chr>    
# 1 a         c        
# 2 a         d        
# 3 b         e
```

---

***Data***

```
df <- data.frame(chapterid = c("a", "b"))
df$part_list <- list(c("c", "d"), "e")

#   chapterid part_list
# 1         a      c, d
# 2         b         e
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R option (Thanks for example data from [@Darren Tsai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63014178/12158757))

```
dfout <- setNames(with(df,data.frame(rep(chapterid,lengths(part_list)),unlist(part_list))),names(df))
```

which gives

```
> dfout
  chapterid part_list
1         a         c
2         a         d
3         b         e
```